# multiply certain dataframe columns by other columns and store the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame called stockData a very cut down version cab be seen below.

```
date        BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST BBG.XLON.BTA.S_FX   BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST BBG.XLON.VOD.S_FX
30/01/2008  257.25              1.337               176.9               1.337
31/01/2008  259                 1.3375              175.3               1.3375
01/02/2008  264.5               1.3277              181.3               1.3277
04/02/2008  262                 1.3307              177.9               1.3307
```

The dataframe has 2 columns per stock at the moment nut may have more (there will also be hundreds of stocks in here eventually).  Is there a way to multiply for each stock the _LAST column by the _FX column? So I would end up with a dataframe that looked like:

```
date        BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST BBG.XLON.BTA.S_FX     BBG.XLON.BTA.S_EUR    BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST BBG.XLON.VOD.S_FX   BBG.XLON.VOD.S_EUR
30/01/2008  257.25              1.337                 343.94                176.9               1.337               236.515
31/01/2008  259                 1.3375                346.4125              175.3               1.3375              234.463
01/02/2008  264.5               1.3277                351.1767              181.3               1.3277              240.463
04/02/2008  262                 1.3307                348.6434              177.9               1.3307              236.731
```

Many thanks

Comment: does `df.ix[:,::2].mul(df.ix[:,1::2].values)` work?

Comment: Are you getting your data already in this _pivoted_ format or you do it yourself? It would be so much easier to process your data if you would have your data vertically with an additional `company` column. Almost all your last questions are about - how to deal with this data structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `for` loop to accomplish that.

```
#column names selection (it assume that the columns base name has a fixed length and starts by BBG)
In [54]: columns_prefix = set([col[0:14] for col in df.columns if col.startswith("BBG")])

In [55]: columns_prefix
Out[55]: {'BBG.XLON.BTA.S', 'BBG.XLON.VOD.S'}

In [56]: for pre in columns_prefix:
   ....:     df[pre+"_EUR"] =df[pre+"_FX"]*df[pre+"_LAST"]
   ....:

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
         date  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_FX  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  \
0  30/01/2008               257.25             1.3370                176.9
1  31/01/2008               259.00             1.3375                175.3
2  01/02/2008               264.50             1.3277                181.3
3  04/02/2008               262.00             1.3307                177.9

   BBG.XLON.VOD.S_FX  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_EUR  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_EUR
0             1.3370           343.94325           236.51530
1             1.3375           346.41250           234.46375
2             1.3277           351.17665           240.71201
3             1.3307           348.64340           236.73153
```

i hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

The pandas package already does scalar products very efficiently (as it is coded in C):

```
df['BBG.XLON.BTA.S_EUR'] = df['BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST']*df['BBG.XLON.BTA.S_FX']
df['BBG.XLON.VOD.S_EUR'] = df['BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST']*df['BBG.XLON.VOD.S_FX']
```

If you don't want to manually enter you categories, you can first create their list:

```
cat_list = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)/2):
    cat_list.append(df.columns[2*i][:-2])
```

And then automatically create your new columns:

```
for cat_name in cat_list:
    df[cat_name + 'EUR'] = df[cat_name + 'FX']*df[cat_name + 'LAST']
```